# Angular JS routing doesn't work for IE 6

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, angularjs-routing

I am currently studying the ability of using AngularJS ( v1.2.16 ) for a project, which must be compatible with our good oldies IE 6+.

I am testing the angular tutorial with these different environments and my first tricky problem lies (as many people) with the Angular routing (step 7).
Everything works fine for IE 7+, which is a good start but I have to make it work with IE6, even by avoiding the angular routing with another solution.

Current behaviour on IE6 : all asked pages are redirected into the otherwise page.

My question : Did someone succeed in doing it on IE6 ? (I know that it's no more tested by the Angular team, although it works on IE7+ with some added code)

Thanks!

Here is my code :
**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"  id="ng-app" ng-app="phonecatApp" >
    <head>

    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <script src="js/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script>
          document.createElement('ng-include');
          document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
          document.createElement('ng-view');


          // Optionally these for CSS
          document.createElement('ng:include');
          document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
          document.createElement('ng:view');

        </script>
    <![endif]-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js :**

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers',
  'phonecatFilters'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        template: '<div ng-include src="\'partials/phone-list.html\'"></div>',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/lol', {
      template: '<div ng-include src="\'partials/kiddin.html\'"></div>',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

**kiddin.html :**

```
<span>Kidding me!</span>
```

**phone-list.html :**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->

      Search: <input ng-model="query">
      Sort by:
      <select ng-model="orderProp">
        <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="age">Newest</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <!--Body content-->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you've already seen Angular's [IE Compatibility page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) and the workarounds for IE7.  Good luck with IE6...

Comment: Thanks I'll keep this updated when I ever find a solution

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS does not support IE6.

Angular 1.2 supports IE8.

Angular 1.3 support IE9 and up.

More details on their [Internet Explorer Compatibility page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: No explicit statement is made that angular does not support IE6 on their compatibility page. Mention is made of support for IE7 with workarounds, so I believe your answer is incorrect

Comment: @GregWoods - there's no explicit statement that Angular does not support IE5 (or Mosaic/Netscape for that matter), but I'm guessing Angular doesn't support any of those browsers either...

Comment: a good point. My own (possibly incorrect) assumption was IE6 is closely related to IE7, so should have a similar level of compatibility. My (limited) testing confirms that code which has been coerced into working with IE7 also works with IE6 - though it is by no means an enjoyable experience!

Comment: You are wrong according to documentation it says "We do not run tests on IE8 and below. A subset of the AngularJS functionality may work on these browsers, but it is up to you to test and decide whether it works for your particular app."

Comment: @gmanolache - Angular 1.3 [dropped support of IE8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), but it was supported in 1.2